# Created technical committee Rogan Council does not appear in PolkadotJS app's Governance tab and unable to create a motion

Tags: governance, pallet-collective

I have the following Subtrate runtime configuration

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
// `construct_runtime!` does a lot of recursion and requires us to increase the limit to 256.
#![recursion_limit = "256"]

// Make the WASM binary available.
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/wasm_binary.rs"));

use pallet_grandpa::{
    fg_primitives, AuthorityId as GrandpaId, AuthorityList as GrandpaAuthorityList,
};
use primitives::{
    types::{CollectionType, NftPermissions},
    CollectionId, ItemId,
};
use sp_api::impl_runtime_apis;
use sp_consensus_aura::sr25519::AuthorityId as AuraId;
use sp_core::{crypto::KeyTypeId, OpaqueMetadata};
use sp_runtime::{
    create_runtime_str, generic, impl_opaque_keys,
    traits::{
        AccountIdLookup, BlakeTwo256, Block as BlockT, IdentifyAccount, NumberFor, One, Verify,
    },
    transaction_validity::{TransactionSource, TransactionValidity},
    ApplyExtrinsicResult, MultiSignature,
};
use sp_std::prelude::*;
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
use sp_version::NativeVersion;
use sp_version::RuntimeVersion;

// A few exports that help ease life for downstream crates.
use frame_support::traits::{EitherOfDiverse, EqualPrivilegeOnly};
pub use frame_support::{
    construct_runtime, parameter_types,
    traits::{
        AsEnsureOriginWithArg, ConstU128, ConstU32, ConstU64, ConstU8, KeyOwnerProofSystem,
        Randomness, StorageInfo,
    },
    weights::{
        constants::{BlockExecutionWeight, ExtrinsicBaseWeight, RocksDbWeight, WEIGHT_PER_SECOND},
        IdentityFee, Weight,
    },
    StorageValue,
};

pub use frame_system::Call as SystemCall;
use frame_system::{EnsureRoot, EnsureSigned};

pub use pallet_balances::Call as BalancesCall;
pub use pallet_timestamp::Call as TimestampCall;
use pallet_transaction_payment::{ConstFeeMultiplier, CurrencyAdapter, Multiplier};
use sp_runtime::traits::OpaqueKeys;
#[cfg(any(feature = "std", test))]
pub use sp_runtime::BuildStorage;
pub use sp_runtime::{Perbill, Permill};

pub use pallet_collective;
pub use pallet_rogan;
pub use pallet_rogan_pepa;
pub use pallet_nft;
pub use pallet_session;
pub use pallet_validator_set;

/// An index to a block.
pub type BlockNumber = u32;

/// Alias to 512-bit hash when used in the context of a transaction signature on the chain.
pub type Signature = MultiSignature;

/// Some way of identifying an account on the chain. We intentionally make it equivalent
/// to the public key of our transaction signing scheme.
pub type AccountId = <<Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;

/// Balance of an account.
pub type Balance = u128;

/// Index of a transaction in the chain.
pub type Index = u32;

/// A hash of some data used by the chain.
pub type Hash = sp_core::H256;

/// Opaque types. These are used by the CLI to instantiate machinery that don't need to know
/// the specifics of the runtime. They can then be made to be agnostic over specific formats
/// of data like extrinsics, allowing for them to continue syncing the network through upgrades
/// to even the core data structures.
pub mod opaque {
    use super::*;

    pub use sp_runtime::OpaqueExtrinsic as UncheckedExtrinsic;

    /// Opaque block header type.
    pub type Header = generic::Header<BlockNumber, BlakeTwo256>;
    /// Opaque block type.
    pub type Block = generic::Block<Header, UncheckedExtrinsic>;
    /// Opaque block identifier type.
    pub type BlockId = generic::BlockId<Block>;

    impl_opaque_keys! {
        pub struct SessionKeys {
            pub aura: Aura,
            pub grandpa: Grandpa,
        }
    }
}
pub mod constants;
use constants::currency::*;

// To learn more about runtime versioning, see:
// https://docs.substrate.io/main-docs/build/upgrade#runtime-versioning
#[sp_version::runtime_version]
pub const VERSION: RuntimeVersion = RuntimeVersion {
    spec_name: create_runtime_str!("node-rogan"),
    impl_name: create_runtime_str!("node-rogan"),
    authoring_version: 1,
    spec_version: 104,
    impl_version: 1,
    apis: RUNTIME_API_VERSIONS,
    transaction_version: 1,
    state_version: 1,
};

/// This determines the average expected block time that we are targeting.
/// Blocks will be produced at a minimum duration defined by `SLOT_DURATION`.
/// `SLOT_DURATION` is picked up by `pallet_timestamp` which is in turn picked
/// up by `pallet_aura` to implement `fn slot_duration()`.
///
/// Change this to adjust the block time.
pub const MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK: u64 = 12000;

// NOTE: Currently it is not possible to change the slot duration after the chain has started.
//       Attempting to do so will brick block production.
pub const SLOT_DURATION: u64 = MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK;

// Time is measured by number of blocks.
pub const MINUTES: BlockNumber = 60_000 / (MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK as BlockNumber);
pub const HOURS: BlockNumber = MINUTES * 60;
pub const DAYS: BlockNumber = HOURS * 24;

/// The version information used to identify this runtime when compiled natively.
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
pub fn native_version() -> NativeVersion {
    NativeVersion { runtime_version: VERSION, can_author_with: Default::default() }
}

const NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO: Perbill = Perbill::from_percent(75);

parameter_types! {
    pub const BlockHashCount: BlockNumber = 2400;
    pub const Version: RuntimeVersion = VERSION;
    /// We allow for 2 seconds of compute with a 6 second average block time.
    pub BlockWeights: frame_system::limits::BlockWeights = frame_system::limits::BlockWeights
        ::with_sensible_defaults(2u64 * WEIGHT_PER_SECOND, NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);
    pub BlockLength: frame_system::limits::BlockLength = frame_system::limits::BlockLength
        ::max_with_normal_ratio(5 * 1024 * 1024, NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO);
    pub const SS58Prefix: u8 = 42;
}

// Configure FRAME pallets to include in runtime.

impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    /// The basic call filter to use in dispatchable.
    type BaseCallFilter = frame_support::traits::Everything;
    /// Block & extrinsics weights: base values and limits.
    type BlockWeights = BlockWeights;
    /// The maximum length of a block (in bytes).
    type BlockLength = BlockLength;
    /// The ubiquitous origin type.
    type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
    /// The aggregated dispatch type that is available for extrinsics.
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    /// The index type for storing how many extrinsics an account has signed.
    type Index = Index;
    /// The index type for blocks.
    type BlockNumber = BlockNumber;
    /// The type for hashing blocks and tries.
    type Hash = Hash;
    /// The hashing algorithm used.
    type Hashing = BlakeTwo256;
    /// The identifier used to distinguish between accounts.
    type AccountId = AccountId;
    /// The lookup mechanism to get account ID from whatever is passed in dispatchers.
    type Lookup = AccountIdLookup<AccountId, ()>;
    /// The header type.
    type Header = generic::Header<BlockNumber, BlakeTwo256>;
    /// The ubiquitous event type.
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    /// Maximum number of block number to block hash mappings to keep (oldest pruned first).
    type BlockHashCount = BlockHashCount;
    /// The weight of database operations that the runtime can invoke.
    type DbWeight = RocksDbWeight;
    /// Version of the runtime.
    type Version = Version;
    /// Converts a module to the index of the module in `construct_runtime!`.
    ///
    /// This type is being generated by `construct_runtime!`.
    type PalletInfo = PalletInfo;
    /// The data to be stored in an account.
    type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData<Balance>;
    /// What to do if a new account is created.
    type OnNewAccount = ();
    /// What to do if an account is fully reaped from the system.
    type OnKilledAccount = ();
    /// Weight information for the extrinsics of this pallet.
    type SystemWeightInfo = ();
    /// This is used as an identifier of the chain. 42 is the generic substrate prefix.
    type SS58Prefix = SS58Prefix;
    /// The set code logic, just the default since we're not a parachain.
    type OnSetCode = ();
    type MaxConsumers = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<16>;
}

impl pallet_randomness_collective_flip::Config for Runtime {}

impl pallet_aura::Config for Runtime {
    type AuthorityId = AuraId;
    type MaxAuthorities = ConstU32<32>;
    type DisabledValidators = ();
}

impl pallet_grandpa::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;

    type KeyOwnerProof =
        <Self::KeyOwnerProofSystem as KeyOwnerProofSystem<(KeyTypeId, GrandpaId)>>::Proof;

    type KeyOwnerIdentification = <Self::KeyOwnerProofSystem as KeyOwnerProofSystem<(
        KeyTypeId,
        GrandpaId,
    )>>::IdentificationTuple;

    type KeyOwnerProofSystem = ();

    type HandleEquivocation = ();

    type WeightInfo = ();
    type MaxAuthorities = ConstU32<32>;
}

impl pallet_timestamp::Config for Runtime {
    /// A timestamp: milliseconds since the unix epoch.
    type Moment = u64;
    type OnTimestampSet = Aura;
    type MinimumPeriod = ConstU64<{ SLOT_DURATION / 2 }>;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}

/// Existential deposit.
pub const EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT: u128 = 600;

impl pallet_balances::Config for Runtime {
    /// The type for recording an account's balance.
    type Balance = Balance;
    type DustRemoval = ();
    /// The ubiquitous event type.
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type ExistentialDeposit = ConstU128<EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT>;
    type AccountStore = System;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_balances::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
    type MaxLocks = ConstU32<50>;
    type MaxReserves = ();
    type ReserveIdentifier = [u8; 8];
}

parameter_types! {
    pub FeeMultiplier: Multiplier = Multiplier::one();
}

impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, ()>;
    type OperationalFeeMultiplier = ConstU8<5>;
    type WeightToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type LengthToFee = IdentityFee<Balance>;
    type FeeMultiplierUpdate = ConstFeeMultiplier<FeeMultiplier>;
}

impl pallet_sudo::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const MinimumOfferAmount: Balance = UNITS / 100;
    pub const RoyaltyBondAmount: Balance = 0;
    pub ReserveCollectionIdUpTo: u128 = 999_999;
}

impl pallet_nft::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_nft::weights::NFTWeight<Runtime>;
    type MinimumOfferAmount = MinimumOfferAmount;
    type RoyaltyBondAmount = RoyaltyBondAmount;
    type NftCollectionId = CollectionId;
    type NftItemId = ItemId;
    type CollectionType = CollectionType;
    type Permissions = NftPermissions;
    type ReserveCollectionIdUpTo = ();
}


impl pallet_rogan::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type ExternalOrigin = RootOrAtLeastHalfOfCommittee;
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const CollectionDeposit: Balance = 10 * CENTS;
    pub const ItemDeposit: Balance = DOLLARS;
    pub const KeyLimit: u32 = 32;
    pub const ValueLimit: u32 = 256;
    pub const UniquesMetadataDepositBase: Balance = 10 * CENTS;
    pub const AttributeDepositBase: Balance = 10 * CENTS;
    pub const DepositPerByte: Balance = CENTS;
    pub const UniquesStringLimit: u32 = 128;
    pub const MaxPropertiesPerTheme: u32 = 100;
    pub const MaxCollectionsEquippablePerPart: u32 = 100;
}

impl pallet_uniques::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type CollectionId = u32;
    type ItemId = u32;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type ForceOrigin = frame_system::EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type CreateOrigin = AsEnsureOriginWithArg<EnsureSigned<AccountId>>;
    type Locker = ();
    type CollectionDeposit = CollectionDeposit;
    type ItemDeposit = ItemDeposit;
    type MetadataDepositBase = UniquesMetadataDepositBase;
    type AttributeDepositBase = AttributeDepositBase;
    type DepositPerByte = DepositPerByte;
    type StringLimit = UniquesStringLimit;
    type KeyLimit = KeyLimit;
    type ValueLimit = ValueLimit;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const MaxMetadataSize: u32 = 2048;
    pub const MaxDIDsPerAccount: u32 = 100;
    pub const PublicKeySize: u32 = 128;
    pub const VCFingerPrintSize: u32 = 32;
    pub const DIDURISize: u32 = 57;
}

impl pallet_rogan_pepa::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type MetadataSize = MaxMetadataSize;
    type MaxDIDsPerAccount = MaxDIDsPerAccount;
    type PublicKeySize = PublicKeySize;
    type VCFingerPrintSize = VCFingerPrintSize;
    type DIDURISize = DIDURISize;
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const CouncilMotionDuration: BlockNumber = 2 * MINUTES;
    pub const CouncilMaxProposals: u32 = 10;
    pub const CouncilMaxMembers: u32 = 5;
}

type TechnicalCollective = pallet_collective::Instance1;

impl pallet_collective::Config<TechnicalCollective> for Runtime {
    type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
    type Proposal = RuntimeCall;
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type MotionDuration = CouncilMotionDuration;
    type MaxProposals = CouncilMaxProposals;
    type MaxMembers = CouncilMaxMembers;
    type DefaultVote = pallet_collective::PrimeDefaultVote;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_collective::weights::SubstrateWeight<Runtime>;
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const Period: u32 = 2 * MINUTES;
    pub const Offset: u32 = 0;
}

impl pallet_session::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type ValidatorId = <Self as frame_system::Config>::AccountId;
    type ValidatorIdOf = pallet_validator_set::ValidatorOf<Self>;
    type ShouldEndSession = pallet_session::PeriodicSessions<Period, Offset>;
    type NextSessionRotation = pallet_session::PeriodicSessions<Period, Offset>;
    type SessionManager = ValidatorSet;
    type SessionHandler = <opaque::SessionKeys as OpaqueKeys>::KeyTypeIdProviders;
    type Keys = opaque::SessionKeys;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const PreimageMaxSize: u32 = 4096 * 1024;
}

impl pallet_preimage::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type Currency = Balances;
    type ManagerOrigin = RootOrAtLeastHalfOfCommittee;
    type MaxSize = PreimageMaxSize;
    type BaseDeposit = ();
    type ByteDeposit = ();
}

parameter_types! {
    pub MaximumSchedulerWeight: Weight = Perbill::from_percent(80) *
    BlockWeights::get().max_block;
    pub const MaxScheduledPerBlock: u32 = 50;
    pub const NoPreimagePostponement: Option<u32> = Some(10);
}

impl pallet_scheduler::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeOrigin = RuntimeOrigin;
    type PalletsOrigin = OriginCaller;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    type MaximumWeight = MaximumSchedulerWeight;
    type ScheduleOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    type OriginPrivilegeCmp = frame_support::traits::EqualPrivilegeOnly;
    type MaxScheduledPerBlock = MaxScheduledPerBlock;
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type PreimageProvider = ();
    type NoPreimagePostponement = NoPreimagePostponement;
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const MinAuthorities: u32 = 2;
}

type EnsureRootOrHalfCouncil = EitherOfDiverse<
    EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
    pallet_collective::EnsureProportionMoreThan<AccountId, TechnicalCollective, 1, 2>,
>;

type RootOrAtLeastHalfOfCommittee = EitherOfDiverse<
    EnsureRoot<AccountId>,
    pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, TechnicalCollective, 1, 2>,
>;

impl pallet_validator_set::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    // see readme for type declaration
    type AddRemoveOrigin = EnsureRootOrHalfCouncil;
    type MinAuthorities = MinAuthorities;
}

// Create the runtime by composing the FRAME pallets that were previously configured.
construct_runtime!(
    pub struct Runtime
    where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system,
        RandomnessCollectiveFlip: pallet_randomness_collective_flip,
        Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
        Balances: pallet_balances,

        ValidatorSet: pallet_validator_set,
        Session: pallet_session,
        Aura: pallet_aura,
        Grandpa: pallet_grandpa,

        TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment,
        Sudo: pallet_sudo,

        ROGANCouncil: pallet_collective::<Instance1>,

        ROGAN: pallet_rogan,
        NFT: pallet_nft,
        Uniques: pallet_uniques::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
        Scheduler: pallet_scheduler,

        Preimage: pallet_preimage,

        ROGANDID: pallet_rogan_pepa::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},

    }
);

/// The address format for describing accounts.
pub type Address = sp_runtime::MultiAddress<AccountId, ()>;
/// Block header type as expected by this runtime.
pub type Header = generic::Header<BlockNumber, BlakeTwo256>;
/// Block type as expected by this runtime.
pub type Block = generic::Block<Header, UncheckedExtrinsic>;
/// The SignedExtension to the basic transaction logic.
pub type SignedExtra = (
    frame_system::CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckTxVersion<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckGenesis<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckEra<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckNonce<Runtime>,
    frame_system::CheckWeight<Runtime>,
    pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>,
);

/// Unchecked extrinsic type as expected by this runtime.
pub type UncheckedExtrinsic =
    generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, RuntimeCall, Signature, SignedExtra>;
/// The payload being signed in transactions.
pub type SignedPayload = generic::SignedPayload<RuntimeCall, SignedExtra>;
/// Executive: handles dispatch to the various modules.
pub type Executive = frame_executive::Executive<
    Runtime,
    Block,
    frame_system::ChainContext<Runtime>,
    Runtime,
    AllPalletsWithSystem,
>;

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
#[macro_use]
extern crate frame_benchmarking;

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
mod benches {
    define_benchmarks!(
        [frame_benchmarking, BaselineBench::<Runtime>]
        [frame_system, SystemBench::<Runtime>]
        [pallet_balances, Balances]
        [pallet_timestamp, Timestamp]
        [pallet_rogan, ROGAN]
        [pallet_nft, NFT]
        [pallet_validator_set, ValidatorSet]
        [pallet_collective, ROGANCouncil]
        [pallet_rogan_pepa, ROGANPEPA]

    );
}

impl_runtime_apis! {
    impl sp_api::Core<Block> for Runtime {
        fn version() -> RuntimeVersion {
            VERSION
        }

        fn execute_block(block: Block) {
            Executive::execute_block(block);
        }

        fn initialize_block(header: &<Block as BlockT>::Header) {
            Executive::initialize_block(header)
        }
    }

    impl sp_api::Metadata<Block> for Runtime {
        fn metadata() -> OpaqueMetadata {
            OpaqueMetadata::new(Runtime::metadata().into())
        }
    }

    impl sp_block_builder::BlockBuilder<Block> for Runtime {
        fn apply_extrinsic(extrinsic: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic) -> ApplyExtrinsicResult {
            Executive::apply_extrinsic(extrinsic)
        }

        fn finalize_block() -> <Block as BlockT>::Header {
            Executive::finalize_block()
        }

        fn inherent_extrinsics(data: sp_inherents::InherentData) -> Vec<<Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic> {
            data.create_extrinsics()
        }

        fn check_inherents(
            block: Block,
            data: sp_inherents::InherentData,
        ) -> sp_inherents::CheckInherentsResult {
            data.check_extrinsics(&block)
        }
    }

    impl sp_transaction_pool::runtime_api::TaggedTransactionQueue<Block> for Runtime {
        fn validate_transaction(
            source: TransactionSource,
            tx: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            block_hash: <Block as BlockT>::Hash,
        ) -> TransactionValidity {
            Executive::validate_transaction(source, tx, block_hash)
        }
    }

    impl sp_offchain::OffchainWorkerApi<Block> for Runtime {
        fn offchain_worker(header: &<Block as BlockT>::Header) {
            Executive::offchain_worker(header)
        }
    }

    impl sp_consensus_aura::AuraApi<Block, AuraId> for Runtime {
        fn slot_duration() -> sp_consensus_aura::SlotDuration {
            sp_consensus_aura::SlotDuration::from_millis(Aura::slot_duration())
        }

        fn authorities() -> Vec<AuraId> {
            Aura::authorities().into_inner()
        }
    }

    impl sp_session::SessionKeys<Block> for Runtime {
        fn generate_session_keys(seed: Option<Vec<u8>>) -> Vec<u8> {
            opaque::SessionKeys::generate(seed)
        }

        fn decode_session_keys(
            encoded: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> Option<Vec<(Vec<u8>, KeyTypeId)>> {
            opaque::SessionKeys::decode_into_raw_public_keys(&encoded)
        }
    }

    impl fg_primitives::GrandpaApi<Block> for Runtime {
        fn grandpa_authorities() -> GrandpaAuthorityList {
            Grandpa::grandpa_authorities()
        }

        fn current_set_id() -> fg_primitives::SetId {
            Grandpa::current_set_id()
        }

        fn submit_report_equivocation_unsigned_extrinsic(
            _equivocation_proof: fg_primitives::EquivocationProof<
                <Block as BlockT>::Hash,
                NumberFor<Block>,
            >,
            _key_owner_proof: fg_primitives::OpaqueKeyOwnershipProof,
        ) -> Option<()> {
            None
        }

        fn generate_key_ownership_proof(
            _set_id: fg_primitives::SetId,
            _authority_id: GrandpaId,
        ) -> Option<fg_primitives::OpaqueKeyOwnershipProof> {
            // NOTE: this is the only implementation possible since we've
            // defined our key owner proof type as a bottom type (i.e. a type
            // with no values).
            None
        }
    }

    impl frame_system_rpc_runtime_api::AccountNonceApi<Block, AccountId, Index> for Runtime {
        fn account_nonce(account: AccountId) -> Index {
            System::account_nonce(account)
        }
    }

    impl pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::TransactionPaymentApi<Block, Balance> for Runtime {
        fn query_info(
            uxt: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::RuntimeDispatchInfo<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_info(uxt, len)
        }
        fn query_fee_details(
            uxt: <Block as BlockT>::Extrinsic,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment::FeeDetails<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_fee_details(uxt, len)
        }
    }

    impl pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api::TransactionPaymentCallApi<Block, Balance, RuntimeCall>
        for Runtime
    {
        fn query_call_info(
            call: RuntimeCall,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment::RuntimeDispatchInfo<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_call_info(call, len)
        }
        fn query_call_fee_details(
            call: RuntimeCall,
            len: u32,
        ) -> pallet_transaction_payment::FeeDetails<Balance> {
            TransactionPayment::query_call_fee_details(call, len)
        }
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    impl frame_benchmarking::Benchmark<Block> for Runtime {
        fn benchmark_metadata(extra: bool) -> (
            Vec<frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkList>,
            Vec<frame_support::traits::StorageInfo>,
        ) {
            use frame_benchmarking::{baseline, Benchmarking, BenchmarkList};
            use frame_support::traits::StorageInfoTrait;
            use frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet as SystemBench;
            use baseline::Pallet as BaselineBench;

            let mut list = Vec::<BenchmarkList>::new();
            list_benchmarks!(list, extra);

            let storage_info = AllPalletsWithSystem::storage_info();

            (list, storage_info)
        }

        fn dispatch_benchmark(
            config: frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkConfig
        ) -> Result<Vec<frame_benchmarking::BenchmarkBatch>, sp_runtime::RuntimeString> {
            use frame_benchmarking::{baseline, Benchmarking, BenchmarkBatch, TrackedStorageKey};

            use frame_system_benchmarking::Pallet as SystemBench;
            use baseline::Pallet as BaselineBench;

            impl frame_system_benchmarking::Config for Runtime {}
            impl baseline::Config for Runtime {}

            use frame_support::traits::WhitelistedStorageKeys;
            let whitelist: Vec<TrackedStorageKey> = AllPalletsWithSystem::whitelisted_storage_keys();

            let mut batches = Vec::<BenchmarkBatch>::new();
            let params = (&config, &whitelist);
            add_benchmarks!(params, batches);

            Ok(batches)
        }
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "try-runtime")]
    impl frame_try_runtime::TryRuntime<Block> for Runtime {
        fn on_runtime_upgrade() -> (Weight, Weight) {
            // NOTE: intentional unwrap: we don't want to propagate the error backwards, and want to
            // have a backtrace here. If any of the pre/post migration checks fail, we shall stop
            // right here and right now.
            let weight = Executive::try_runtime_upgrade().unwrap();
            (weight, BlockWeights::get().max_block)
        }

        fn execute_block(
            block: Block,
            state_root_check: bool,
            select: frame_try_runtime::TryStateSelect
        ) -> Weight {
            // NOTE: intentional unwrap: we don't want to propagate the error backwards, and want to
            // have a backtrace here.
            Executive::try_execute_block(block, state_root_check, select).expect("execute-block failed")
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use frame_support::traits::WhitelistedStorageKeys;
    use sp_core::hexdisplay::HexDisplay;
    use std::collections::HashSet;

    #[test]
    fn check_whitelist() {
        let whitelist: HashSet<String> = AllPalletsWithSystem::whitelisted_storage_keys()
            .iter()
            .map(|e| HexDisplay::from(&e.key).to_string())
            .collect();

        // Block Number
        assert!(
            whitelist.contains("26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef702a5c1b19ab7a04f536c519aca4983ac")
        );
        // Total Issuance
        assert!(
            whitelist.contains("c2261276cc9d1f8598ea4b6a74b15c2f57c875e4cff74148e4628f264b974c80")
        );
        // Execution Phase
        assert!(
            whitelist.contains("26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7ff553b5a9862a516939d82b3d3d8661a")
        );
        // Event Count
        assert!(
            whitelist.contains("26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef70a98fdbe9ce6c55837576c60c7af3850")
        );
        // System Events
        assert!(
            whitelist.contains("26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef780d41e5e16056765bc8461851072c9d7")
        );
    }
}
```

I have configured the governance as `ROGANCouncil`

But this is not appearing on PolkadotJS Technical Committee tab and Im unable tp create motions. How to fix this issue ? It only shows `preimage` in Governance

and how to create a motion and execute extinsics?

[image]